# jQuery (UI): Detect checking of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, jquery-events

How can I make jQuery fire an event when a user checks a checkbox?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" /><label for="test">Check me</label>
```

I could do it with .click though that doesn't work when the user tabs to the checkbox. I wasn't able to find info on this in the API docs or while Googling.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('#test').bind('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        // box was checked
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [`change` event](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
$('#test').change(function() { ... });
```